# LoopBackJs REST API Create response not returning full model, only form data

Tags: loopbackjs

when I POST to api/testmodel using an object with only the required fields, the object is being created correctly in the DB. However, I only get the object I sent in the request body. I'm trying to get the full object with null fields in the response.

Thanks for the help!

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "plural": "test",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "replaceOnPUT": false,
  "properties": {
    "city": {
      "type": "string",
      "length": 100
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true,
      "length": 100
    },
    "id": {
      "type": "string",
      "id": true,
      "required": true,
    },
    "officePhone": {
      "type": "string",
      "length": 100
    },
    "status": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": false,
      "length": 200
    },
    "street": {
      "type": "string",
      "length": 100
    }
  },
 "methods": {}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you need to create default values for your model, for example city:

```
"properties": {
    "city": {
      "type": "string",
      "length": 100,
      "default": ""

    },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, after you have created your new record and have the record ID, perform a `findById` query and return that object instead of the object returned from `create`.  This should give you a response similar to a GET route.